# Handing StopIteration in Python

Tags: python, loops, return, iteration, stopiteration

I tried to code and get the right fitness_point here but after the loop the result keep showing as 0. It first showing the StopIteration, so I write try and except there, but the result is still wrong..
I am a completely newbie here, what should I do? please help..

```
population={'list_1':[0,2,3,4],'list_2':[2,0,4,1],'list_3':[1,6,0,8],'list_4':[3,5,6,0]}

item = [3,4,2,1]

def get_fitness(items):
    g= iter(items)
    temp=[]
    fitness_point=0
    try:
        for i in items:
            if i != items[3]:
                temp=population['list_{}'.format(i)]
                fitness_point+=temp[g.__next__()-1]
                print(fitness_point)
    except GeneratorExit:
        return 'eror'

return fitness_point

print(get_fitness(item))
```

Comment: Please clarify your expected output

Comment: Why do you use the iterator `g`? With your approach `g.__next__()-1` is always `i - 1`.

Comment: Short version of your code: `return sum(population['list_{}'.format(i)][i-1] for i in items[:-1])`.